# XPages Richttext upload image does not work - Search button hidden

Tags: image, xpages, rich-text-editor

I'm using an Richtext Field in my XPage and I want to embed an image. So I click on the icon in the action bar of the editor and the dialog opens. But in Internet Explorer 11 it looks like this:

[image]

So I can not select the file I want to upload.
If I open the XPage in Firefox and want to upload an image it works, but not with IE 11.

It seems like the page containing the search button could not be loaded.
If i resize the scroll bars I can see an error page "Site could not be found. Make sure the address //ieframe.dll/dnserrordiagoff.htm# is corrent"

Notes Server Version: 9.0.1 FP1

Can anyone give me a hint here?

Comment: It's worth including the Domino server version, including fix pack. That may be relevant.

Comment: Ok, I've added that information above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [fix list link](http://m.ibm.com/http/www-10.lotus.com/ldd/fixlist.nsf/8d1c0550e6242b69852570c900549a74/7ff6a78cb16153d085257d2b0062d7b8?OpenDocument&wirelessshow=1). IE 11 support was only added in FP2. It's covered by SPR# TMGN9KJTEB